# Typescript instanceof does not work on my API Gateway

Tags: node.js, typescript, api, serverless

I have this for manage errors on my Typescript serverless API Gateway

```
export abstract class ErrorResult extends Error {
  public constructor(public code: string, public description: string) {
    super(description);
  }
}

export class BadRequestResult extends ErrorResult {}

export class ConfigurationErrorResult extends ErrorResult {}

export class ForbiddenResult extends ErrorResult {}

export class InternalServerErrorResult extends ErrorResult {}

export class NotFoundResult extends ErrorResult {}
```

I'm making this

```
let error: NotFoundResult = new NotFoundResult('UNKNOWN_USER', 'There is no user with the specified ID!');
          if(error instanceof NotFoundResult) {
            console.log('WORK!!!');
          }
```

but message is not showed, what is my error?

Comment: You're creating it, but that's it.  Are you throwing it too?

Answer (score 0):

> but message is not showed

It shows just fine. Here is the example code along with working demo:

```
abstract class ErrorResult extends Error {
    public constructor(public code: string, public description: string) {
        super(description);
    }
}
class NotFoundResult extends ErrorResult { }
let error: NotFoundResult = new NotFoundResult(
    'UNKNOWN_USER',
    'There is no user with the specified ID!'
);
if (error instanceof NotFoundResult) {
    console.log('WORK!!!');
}
```

[image]